# URL masking via VHOST or htaccess

Tags: url, apache2, dns, masking

I would like to fake mask URL to another url..
Example:
I have domain www.domain.tld.. 
And I want to mask it to www.google.com
So, if someone type www.domain.tld/something, it will load URL www.google.com/something - without redirect!
Is it possible? Both domains are mine.
I can use VHOSTS, or htaccess..

Comment: Ok, I dont want to redirect. I want only the first domain to be visible. So, how about proxy? (EDIT: where's the previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

If both your domains are served by the same server, you can use an internal URL rewrite to do this. Apache would internally server the content from domain B when a request comes in for domain A. The [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) documentation has all the information. It's very powerful, so there are many options.

Comment: No, they are on different servers. One is on VPS and second is on shared hosting.